# Can't use union_relations from dbt_utils package

Tags: macros, union, dbt

I started working back again on some old code I was working on some months ago. It was executing correctly then but now when I dbt run my model, I get the error:

```
'dbt.clients.jinja.MacroGenerator object' has no attribute 'union_relations'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist.
```

My code starts with:

```
{{ dbt_utils.union_relations(

    relations=[ref('src'), ref('src2'), ref('src3'), ref('src4'), ref('src5')]

) }}

select 
MAX(REPORTEDDATE) AS REPORTEDDATE,
USERID, ....
```

Even though I have a packages.yml file at the project's root level with:

```
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
    version: 1.1.1
```

and I did run `dbt deps` prior to execution.

Any ideas on what can I be missing here ?

I can see the macro union_relations defined in this path dbt_utils/macros/sql/union.sql
but still dbt doesn't seem to be able to pick it up.